# Lightning Web Component - Navigate With Relationship

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to use NavigationMixin.Navigate to navigate to a new Case and retain the relationship to the current Account?  I have a lightning component with a navigation button that uses the following Page Reference to start a new case from the Account page:

```
this.accountHomePageRef = {
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Case',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
        };
```

In short, I want the new Case to be releated to the Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're saying is you need to populate a field value (in this case the accountId) with the account record where the button was clicked on. unfortunately setting default values on navigateMixin in LWC is not yet supported:

[LWC counterpart to Aura's force:createRecord event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251014/lwc-counterpart-to-auras-forcecreaterecord-event?rq=1)

What you can do instead is create an Aurawrapper component to enclose your LWC. then fire a custom event from lwc that will be responded to by the parent Aura, then Aura launches a createRecord event with the passed account id.

on LWC js:

```
  @api recordId; // build-in keyword to store the current acct record id on page


  _onCreateCase() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onCreateCase', {
            detail: { acctId : this.recordId },
        });
```

on Aura wrapper cmp:

```
<c:childLwc onCreateCase="{!c.handleCreateCase}"/>
```

controller js:

```
handleCreateCase: function(component, event, helper) {
      var acctId = event.getParam('acctId');
      var createEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
            createEvent.setParams({
               "entityApiName" : "Case",
               "defaultFieldValues" : {
                  "AccountId" : acctId
            }
        });
        createEvent.fire();
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components

Comment: It seems like what your explaining will create record, but then how do I open up that record programmatically?

Comment: its the same as a New form with fields populated. You will still have to click on Save or Cancel. Once saved then you will be routed to the new record automatically.