# Standard Create-record modal in LWC without page redirect?

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-records, lightningnavigation

Is it possible to call the standard create record modal without invoking a page redirect. After reading [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251014/lwc-counterpart-to-auras-forcecreaterecord-event) I learned that you can call the create record event using lightning navigation mixin.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
          objectApiName: 'Account',
          actionName: 'new'
        },
        state: {
          nooverride: '1'
        }
      });
```

this works fantastic except for the fact that it redirects the page to the newly created record. Is there currently any way to call the create new record modal without immediately after navigating to the newly created record's page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `lightning-record-form` in LWC to get the full layout without page redirect or without calling any apex method.

Below is the code example:

```
<lightning-record-form  object-api-name="Account" layout-type="Full" columns="2" mode="edit">
                </lightning-record-form>
```

You  can read more about lightning-record-form [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation)

Comment: Thank you this was just what I was looking for

Comment: Always happy to help :)